# how to get a field name by field label in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, entities

I have added a custom field with title 'play time'. How can I get the field name(internal value) using label value in my custom module. Is there any function to get the value?

Comment: No you'll need to query the field info tables manually for that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find specific content types based on field you can use:

```
field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle_name);
```

If you want to find any field you can use:

```
field_info_field_map();
```

In both cases you will get an array of fields and you can get field name by filtering label value.